# Groovy Split CSV

Tags: csv, groovy, split

I have a csv file (details.csv) like

```
ID,NAME,ADDRESS
1,"{foo,bar}","{123,mainst,ny}"
2,"{abc,def}","{124,mainst,Va}"
3,"{pqr,xyz}","{125,mainst,IL}"
```

when I use (Note: I have other closure above this which reads all csv files from directory)

```
if(file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("deatails.csv")) {
 input = new FileInputStream(file)
 reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input))
 reader.eachLine{line-> def cols = line.split(",")
 println cols.size() }
```

Instead of getting size 3 I am getting 6 with values

```
1
"{foo
bar}"
"{123
mainst
ny}"
```

spilt(",") is splitting data by comma(,) but I want my results as

```
1
"{foo,bar}"
"{123,mainst,ny}"
```

How can I fix this closure. Please help! Thanks

Comment: String.split(String regex) will split on whatever regex you pass in there. Since you're just passing in "," it is also splitting on the commas contained in the values. You need a regex that ignores those commas, or find a Java/Groovy library that parses CSV files.

Answer (score 22):

Writing a csv parser is a tricky business.

I would let someone else do the hard work, and use something [like GroovyCsv](https://github.com/xlson/groovycsv/)

---

Here is how to parse it with GroovyCsv

```
// I'm using Grab instead of just adding the jar and its
// dependencies to the classpath
@Grab( 'com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0' )
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def csv = '''ID,NAME,ADDRESS
1,"{foo,bar}","{123,mainst,ny}"
2,"{abc,def}","{124,mainst,Va}"
3,"{pqr,xyz}","{125,mainst,IL}"'''

def csva = CsvParser.parseCsv( csv )
csva.each {
  println it
}
```

Which prints:

```
ID: 1, NAME: {foo,bar}, ADDRESS: {123,mainst,ny}
ID: 2, NAME: {abc,def}, ADDRESS: {124,mainst,Va}
ID: 3, NAME: {pqr,xyz}, ADDRESS: {125,mainst,IL}
```

So, to get the NAME field of the second row, you could do:

```
def csvb = CsvParser.parseCsv( csv )
println csvb[ 1 ].NAME
```

Which prints

```
{abc,def}
```

Of course, if the CSV is a File, you can do:

```
def csvc = new File( 'path/to/csv' ).withReader {
  CsvParser.parseCsv( it )
}
```

Then use it as above

Comment: When I try this api some how it is combining my headers with values and not giving in the format I am looking for. Since i need to complete that ASAP I have followed the first approach in my answer below.

Comment: @springpress Added some code showing how to use it...  As you can see, it *does* work...

Comment: I am not sure if this logic changed, but it is important to note that the format of the csv string defined in the code above is significant.  
    `def csv = '''`  
      header1,header2, header3  
      value1, value2, value3  
    '''`  
will not yield the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing.
One is using collect

```
def processCsvData(Map csvDataMap, File file)
{

    InputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    String[] lines = inputFile.text.split('\n')
    List<String[]> rows = lines.collect {it.split(',')}
          // Add processing logic
}
```

Here problem is it is removing commas in between braces ({}) i.e "{foo,bar}" becomes "{foo bar}"
Another way of using java, and this works just fine

```
public class CSVParser { 

    /* 
     * This Pattern will match on either quoted text or text between commas, including 
     * whitespace, and accounting for beginning and end of line. 
     */ 
    private final Pattern csvPattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?:,|$)");   
    private ArrayList<String> allMatches = null;         
    private Matcher matcher = null; 
    private int size; 

    public CSVParser() {                 
        allMatches = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        matcher = null; 
    } 

    public String[] parse(String csvLine) { 
        matcher = csvPattern.matcher(csvLine); 
        allMatches.clear(); 
        String match; 
        while (matcher.find()) { 
                match = matcher.group(1); 
                if (match!=null) { 
                        allMatches.add(match); 
                } 
                else { 
                        allMatches.add(matcher.group(2)); 
                } 
        } 

        size = allMatches.size();                
        if (size > 0) { 
                return allMatches.toArray(new String[size]); 
        } 
        else { 
                return new String[0]; 
        }                        
    }    

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can rewrite that entire java class in Groovy as `public class CSVParser { public String[] parse( String csvLine ) { def matcher = csvLine =~ /"([^"]*)"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?:,|$)/ ; matcher.collect { it[1] } } }`

Comment: And I would still use a pre-written CSV parsing library

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Nope this class is not working at all. If i print it[1] its printing putting null to each csv column except something inside {} which will not help me sorry! I am planning to live with the solution i provided in first one