# Groovy split csv and empty fields

Tags: groovy

Groovy split seems to be ignoring empty fields.

Here is the code:

```
line = abc,abc,,,
line.split(/,/)
println
```

prints only..

```
abc abc
```

It seems to ignore empty fields. How do I retrieve empty fields using split?

Comment: If you're parsing a CSV, you should be using a [CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995167/groovy-split-csv)

Comment: Correct @tim_yates. I would do the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, method [split(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) is not provided by Groovy, it is provided by Java.

Second, you can achieve what you need by using the generic [split(regex, int limit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) as below:

```
def line = "abc,abc,,,"

println line.split(/,/, -1) //prints [abc, abc, , , ]
println line.split(/,/, -1).size() //prints 5
```

Note:-
The string array you would end up in the print would throw a compilation error when asserted. But you can use the result as a normal list.

```
line.split(/,/, -1).each{println "Hello $it"}
```

I would rather use limit 0 or the overloaded split to discard unwanted empty strings.

*Explanation on using -1 as limit:*
Stress on the below statements from the javadoc.

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Comment: Thanks, your solution saved me from writing a complex regex match just split words. I still can't understand why its not the default behavior of String.split in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. The `split` method works as expected provided there's a non-empty element at the end.

```
def list = 'abc,abc,,,abc'.split(/,/)
println list // prints [abc, abc, , ]
assert list.size() == 5
assert list[0] == 'abc'
assert list[1] == 'abc'
assert list[2] == ''
assert list[3] == ''
assert list[4] == 'abc'
```

Maybe you could just append a bogus character to the end of the string and sublist the result:

```
def list = 'abc,abc,,,X'.split(/,/) - 'X'
println list // prints [abc, abc, , ]
```