# Split a string in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a string `str= ",,,,,"` .I want to split str based on , and wanna get an list with 5 `["","","","",""]` blank.So that i can replace those blanks with values.Finally i want to make a string with comma separated values which initialized only by commas `,,,,,` replace  to `1,2,3,,,` or `,,,1,2,3` or `1,2,3,4,5` etc .Thanks in advance .Any help full learning source also appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i tried String [] strings = str.split(",");

Comment: Actually i tried several ways like List<String> arr=str.split(","); then i tried manually using stringBuffer ,But i think there is easy method in groovy.

Comment: 5 commas means **6** values!

Comment: yes 5 commas mean 6 values

Comment: So you're saying that you think there is an easier way to split a string on commas than `def values = str.split(',',-1)`. Hmmmm.... Nope, doesn't get much easier than that. Now Groovy does help joining them back: `values.join(',')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Java [split(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to achieve your first goal and then groovy syntactic sugar to help with the rest:

```
def str = ",,,,,"

def arr = str.split(/,/, -1)

println arr.size() // 6

arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3

println arr // [1, 2, 3, , , ]
```

See also [Groovy split csv and empty fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605912/groovy-split-csv-and-empty-fields)

Comment: it should be noted, that the very key to the result OP wants is the last param `-1` and _not_ the use of the regexp. `assert []==",".split(",")` vs `assert ["",""]==",".split(",",-1)`