# CsvParser Stream Closed Error When Parsing Multiple Files

Tags: csv, groovy, ioexception

I'm trying to parse a list of CSV files that i get by recursing on a directory. The code below prints only one line and then exists with a Stream Closed Error :

```
def stageDir = new File(STAGE_DIR), listOfFiles = [], filesData = []
// Get the list of files
stageDir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
   listOfFiles << file
}

// Start parsing each CSV file in the list
listOfFiles.each { file ->
   def csvData = file.withReader {
      new CsvParser().parse( it , separator: CSV_SEPARATOR )
   }

   // Here i put the returned csvData (of type CsvIterator) in the filesData
   filesData.add(csvData)
}

// I checked filesData and it's not empty, so i iterate over it.

// HERE I GET : Stream Closed error
// I'm just trying to test by printing the first line of myIt 
// (but is there a more efficient way to iterate over CsvIterator ?)
for (myIt in filesData) {
   println myIt[0].ID + " " + myIt[0].NAME
}
```

Is there a much better way to use CsvParser with multiple files and to avoid the Stream Closed error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add to `filesData` the parsed data but actually result returned by `new File('').withReader{}` which is probably stream or anything else. Instead try:

```
listOfFiles.each { file ->
   def csvData = file.withReader {
      filesData.add(new CsvParser().parse( it , separator: CSV_SEPARATOR ))
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I also doubt if You iterate over `filesData` correctly. In every loop `myIt` isn't a data row but an instance of `Iterable` returned from `parse` method. Can't experiment right now but maybe it should be.

```
for (myIt in filesData) {
   myIt.each { rowIt ->
     println rowIt.ID + " " + rowIt.NAME
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Working example for groovy console

```
@Grab( 'com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0' )
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def csv1 = '''ID,NAME,ADDRESS
1,n1,a1
2,n2,a2
3,n3,a3'''

def csv2 = '''ID,NAME,ADDRESS
4,n4,a4
5,n5,a5
6,n6,a6
'''
def listOfFiles = [csv1, csv2]
def filesData = []

listOfFiles.each { filesData.add(new CsvParser().parse( it , separator: ',' )) }

filesData.each { d ->
    d.each { r ->
        println "$r.ID $r.NAME"
    }
}
```

What You need to do is to check if all file operations run smoothly in the example You provided.

**UPDATE 3 :D**

Here's the sample code with a reproduced error:

```
@Grab( 'com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0' )
import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def f1
def f2 

try {
    f1 = File.createTempFile("temp1",".csv")
    f2 = File.createTempFile("temp2",".csv")
    f1.text = '''ID,NAME,ADDRESS
1,n1,a1
2,n2,a2
3,n3,a3
'''

    f2.text = '''ID,NAME,ADDRESS
4,n4,a4
5,n5,a5
6,n6,a6
'''
    def listOfFiles = [f1, f2]
    def filesData = []

    listOfFiles.each { f ->
        f.withReader { r -> 
            def data = new CsvParser().parse( r , separator: ',' )
            filesData.add(data)
        }
    }

    filesData.each { d ->
        d.each { r ->
            println "$r.ID $r.NAME"
        }
    }
} finally {
    f1?.delete()
    f2?.delete()
}
```

Now.. what's going on here. In `withReader` closure `parse` method of `CsvParser` is invoked with `r` (reader) object passed. But `withReader` closure isn't evaluated eagerly but *lazily*. Then in the place where parsed data are printed the `r` is read and while groovy detects the `EOF` closes the stream automatically (it can be easily verified with changing `3,n3,a3\n'''` to `3,n3,a3'''`. But the class `au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader` (`getNextLine()` method) doesn't check if the stream is closed and try to read it which results in the `Stream closed` exception. Actually this is a bug in `CSVReader` class.

To correct it You need to change lazy reading to eager. This can be done with changing this line of code:

```
filesData.add(data)
```

to this:

```
filesData.add(data.toList())
```

which causes data to be read in the closure and not left for reading later on.

Comment: Still getting the java.io.IOException: Stream closed on the same line : println myIt[0].ID + " " + myIt[0].NAME !

Comment: Ok. Any sample project on the web? Ready to try?

Comment: Samples that i've seen deals with one file and one returned CsvIterator not multiple files :(

Comment: Ok, but do You have any sample project on the web where I can try with?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995167/groovy-split-csv and GroovyCSV's official website: http://xlson.com/groovycsv/

Comment: Will have a look at it in a moment.

Comment: Thanks Opal that helped printing the entire file but still getting Stream closed at the end. I don't know if it had to do with using CsvGroovy inside a quartz job!

Comment: Ok. Will try with files in a moment.

Comment: I used a Thread inside filesData.each { d -> // Thread here } and i got to print all files but still getting Stream closed inside the thread !

Comment: Updated my answer once again. Hope this solves the problem. Thread has nothing to do here.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Opal, coffee is on me! :D

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day, when the file was closed and you tried to read from it an Exception WAS the expected result.

But fear not! The OpenCSV project has a new active developer, Maciek, and he has not only updated the project to Java 7 (since 5 and 6 are no longer supported) he has changed the `CSVReader` to not throw an `IOException` but handle it quietly.

We have pushed this version out on [Sourceforge as version 3.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/opencsv/3.0/).  Please feel free to test it out and update the xlson libraries to the new version.

I have to say I am greatly honored to see our work ending up in other projects.  Its sort of like a guitar maker finding out a famous rock band uses your guitars.