# GROOVY - Parsing CSV: Ignore commas inside double quotes

Tags: csv, groovy, split

I'm looking for a groovy regex to be able to parse CSV file while ignoring commas insider double quotes.
The following regex works well in Java but not in Groovy:

```
it.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
```

Would you please help me to solve this issue.

I want to **validate** a CSv file format, for example for following example, the format is correct or not:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
1, 2, 3
4, "5, 6", 7
```

But in this case, the format is not valid:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
1, 2
```

I check [Groovy Split CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995167/groovy-split-csv) but it didn't solve my problem. Because the solution shown in that article, after parsing following csv:

```
Header1, Header2, Header3
1, "2, 3", 4, 5
```

will match:

```
Header1: 1
Header2: "2, 3"
Header3: 4
```

and it ignores 5! But me, I want to print out a message that format is not correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by saying >regex works well in Java but not in Groovy ?

Answer (score 0):

try to change it like this:

it.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*\${1})")

Let me know.

Comment: explain your question properly we should be tried to give you an answer or help